# Signing PhoneGap build app for distribution. Unable to download

Tags: ios, cordova

Having real trouble signing my PhoneGap Build app for distribution to the AppStore. I was able to successfully sign using a development certificate and build on my designated iPhone device but when installing the ipk using the distribution certificate and provisioning profile I get

"Unable to download"

Steps taken:

1) Created a distributioncertificate signing request in the provisioning portal and downloaded
2) Exported the certificate and key as a .p12 using Key Chain Access
3) Created a distribution provisioning profile for the App.
4) Uploaded the .p12 and provisioning profile to PhoneGap build and unlocked the key
5) Used the QR code to install on an iPhone 4s and iPod Touch but get the Unable to Download error message half way through installing.

My package name as specified in config.xml is: com.myapp.mobile
The App ID (in AppIds page of provisioning portal is: 4DWP3FV5J6.com.myapp.mobile
The provisioning profile status is active and the certificate expiry date is Jan 2014.

I've also tried re-creating all the certificates and with a fresh PhoneGap build account.

Can anyone suggest what might be causing this error or how I can debug to get further information?

Comment: on 5th step , i.e. after unlocking buil -  is to rebuild app. Then download application. At the end deploy to device by connecting to iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

How are you attempting to download the file? E.g. from build.phonegap.com on the mobile device or via the ipa (which I assume if what you meant rather than the ipk)? You'll want to do the former.

Regards,
Kevin